# Wordpress thumbnails size

Tags: wordpress, post, size, overriding

I am having a problem at the site ivanschneider.de regarding the thumbnails for the posts.

I wanted to have big thumbnails with 650 x 0 pixels. So I added this code to k2-loop.php:

```
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php if ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') and has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 650, 0 ), array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) ); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

For now that is working. Whenever I go to the dashboard of Wordpress and set a new image as article thumbnail, it generates the 650 x 0 image and shows it correctly.

But then I am using another plugin called related post thumbnails, which shows some thumnails/links to other related posts. Because I have no small thumbnails set, it shows those thumbnails of those big 650-px-images in small and not proportional, which looks ugly.

So, I went to the options of the media library and set there the thumbnails size to 150 x 150 pixels to have some thumbnails for plugins like this. I thought, it would create them and leave my post thumbnails in peace.

Now my problem: It seems, that overrides the code I entered above into k2-loop.php. In other words, when I want to create a new post and set an image as post thumbnail, the get the small 150 x 150 size instead of the 650 x 0 size I have set in k2-loop.php.

How can I prevent the overrriding of my k2-loop.php code by the media gallery thumbnails settings?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind greetings

Comment: I solved that by putting <?php the_post_thumbnail( medium ); ?></a> instead of the array with 650 x 0.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept the answer to properly close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by putting

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( medium ); ?></a>"
```

instead of the array with 650 x 0.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'news', // custom post type
            'orderby' => 'ID',  // order by ID
            'order' => 'DESC',   
            'posts_per_page' => -1
          
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        
        if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
   
        $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_to_use->ID);

        if ($post_image_id) {$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id,array(150,150));
        if($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];} 
        ?>
        
        <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>" >

      <?php else:  ?>
      <p>
      <?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?>
      </p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
//Default WordPress

Thumbnail Sizes

The default image sizes of WordPress are “thumbnail”, “medium”, “large” and “full” (the size of the image you uploaded). These image sizes can be configured in the WordPress Administration Media panel under Settings > Media. This is how you can use these default sizes with the_post_thumbnail():



the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
 
//With WooCommerce
the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_thumbnail' ); // Shop thumbnail (180 x 180 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_catalog' );   // Shop catalog (300 x 300 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_single' );    // Shop single (600 x 600 hard cropped)


the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );   // custom size add in array.

Register new image sizes for Post Thumbnails with: add_image_size().
To set the default size for Post Thumbnails see: set_post_thumbnail_size().
```